# fetching data from API not working

Tags: javascript, api

I have a local API running on host 8888, and I have a host for the user.

I have the following in the **index.html**

```
<ul class = "list-grouop" id="chats"></ul>
```

and this in the same file ( **index.html** ):

```
<script>

        const url = 'http://localhost:8888/chats';
        const ul = document.getElementById('chats');


        // Create the type of element you pass in the parameters
        function createNode(element) 
        {
            return document.createElement(element); 
        }

        // Append the second parameter(element) to the first one
        function append(parent, el) 
        {
            return parent.appendChild(el); 
        }

        fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json()) 
        .then(function(data) 
        {
              // Create and append the li's to the ul
              let chats = data;
              return chats.map(function(chat) 
              { // Map through the results and for each run the code below
                  let li = createNode('li'), //  Create the elements we need
                  span = createNode('span');
                  span.innerHTML = `${chats[0]}`; // Make the HTML of our span to be the first person in the chat
                  append(li, span);
                  append(ul, li);
              });
        });

    </script>
```

I have the following in the **chats.json** ( the local API) :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "users": ["x", "y"]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,    
    "users": ["x", "z"]
  }
]
```

but the problem is that I am getting this:

> TypeError: chats.map is not a function

when I try to run this:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => { console.log(json) });
```

I am getting this: `

> Object { chats: Array[0] }

This is what I have in the Network:

[image]

Thanks for your time

Comment: where's your fetch function ?

Comment: @digit in `index.html`

Comment: Have you tried `data.chats.map...`?

Comment: looks like you need `let chats = data.chats`

Comment: @sma yes that fixed the problem. Thanks so much. But do u have any idea why I'm getting empty array ?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes that fixed the problem. Thanks so much. But do u have any idea why I'm getting empty array ?

Comment: check the developer tools console or network tab to see what data is being sent by the server

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm already using it this is what is being printed `Object { chats: Array[0] }`

Comment: no, the network tab shows actual data, not the result of console.log

Comment: @JaromandaX I edited the question and added what I get in the network to the end of the question

Comment: yeah, that doesn't show the response data, in fact doesn't even show the request!!! so is pointless addition

Comment: @JaromandaX I got it sorted, thanks  ofr the help:)